# my page is only buffering in php ...... when i put some value in textbox above 1000

Tags: php

```
 <?php print $errors['nofocards']; ?> </td>

                    </tr>
                                <tr align="center" valign="top">                              
                                  <td align="left"> Quantity</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr align="left" valign="top">                        
                                  <td>

                                   <?php

                         $sql = "SELECT q.* FROM custompricing c, quantity q    WHERE q.quantityid=c.quantityid and stocktypeid=$stocktypeid and paperplastictypeid=$paperplastictypeid AND sizespecificationid=$sizespecificationid and paperplasticqualityid=$paperplasticqualityid order by q.quantityid";
                                        //print $sql;
                                        //$sql = "select * from quantity order by priority";

                                        $result = mysql_query($sql,$link);
                                        $isdone = false;
                                        while($ary = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                        {
                                            if($quantityid == $ary['quantityid'])
                                            {
                                                $isdone = true;                                            
                                                $transportpreference = $ary['transportpref'];
                                            }                                       

                                        }
                                        if($isdone == false)
                                        {
                                            $transportpreference = "AR";
                                        }
                                    ?>
              <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
       <input name="txtQuantity" type="text" class="form-control input-md pull-left"  id="txtQuantity" size="9" maxlength="6" onBlur="checkQuantity()" value="<?= $txtQuantity ?>">
       <input name="hndQuantityid" type="hidden" id="hndQuantityid" value="<?= $hndQuantityid ?>">
       <input name="hndCustomQuantity" type="hidden" id="hndCustomQuantity">
       <input name="hndChnage" type="hidden" id="hndChnage" value="custom">
                                         <input name="qtytype" type="hidden" id="qtytype" value="customquantity">
                                  <br>
                                  <br>
                         <p class="text-nowrap">(Please be patient after inserting a custom quantity for the webpage to refresh).</p></td>.
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                                  </td>
                          </tr>
```

javascript code

```
function checkQuantity(){
    qtyval = document.formbasic.txtQuantity.value;
    if (!(IsNumeric(document.formbasic.txtQuantity.value))){
        document.formbasic.hndQuantityid.value = aryQty[0][0];
        document.formbasic.txtQuantity.value = minqty;
        document.formbasic.hndCustomQuantity.value = "no";
    }

    if (maxqty < qtyval){
        document.formbasic.hndQuantityid.value = aryQty[aryQty.length-1][0];
        document.formbasic.txtQuantity.value = maxqty;
        document.formbasic.hndCustomQuantity.value = "no";
    }
//  else if (qtyval == "" || qtyval < minqty){
    else if (qtyval == ""){
        document.formbasic.hndQuantityid.value = aryQty[0][0];
        document.formbasic.txtQuantity.value = minqty;
        document.formbasic.hndCustomQuantity.value = "no";
    }
    else if (qtyval < minqty){
        document.formbasic.hndQuantityid.value = aryQty[0][0];
        document.formbasic.txtQuantity.value = minqty;
        document.formbasic.hndCustomQuantity.value = "yes";
    }
    else {
        getQuantityid(qtyval);
    }

    if (curqtyid != document.formbasic.hndQuantityid.value)
        {
            curqtyid = document.formbasic.hndQuantityid.value;
            submitMethod();
        }
}





when i entered value in Quantity ...say 100 then the page is accepting the value and page load proper and stop ....but when i put value of 1000 then the page continously loading and loading and it does not stop.......
    what is the possible problem in the page?
and my inputbox of Quantity accepts value above 1000 upto 5000....then also the problem persist
how it can be solved?
if needed more code ...i will provide 
how it can be solved?
```

when i entered value in Quantity ...say 100 then the page is accepting the value and page load proper and stop ....but when i put value of 1000 then the page continously buffering  and it does not stop.......
        what is the possible problem in the page?
    and my inputbox of Quantity accepts value above 1000 upto 5000....then also the problem persist
    how it can be solved?
    if needed more code ...i will provide 
    how it can be solved?

[this is the error page only buffering the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NddUA.png)

Comment: I don't quite get the title here. *"my page is loading when i put some value in textbox above 1000"* - Yet alone the question. Edit: Now the title changed. I still don't know what you're asking. Any errors? checking for them at all?

Comment: we don't need code....we need a proper question ;-)

Comment: `onBlur="checkQuantity()"` can you please show the code of this javascript function?

Comment: @prakashtank   ok

Comment: @prakashtank i have added the javascript code ....now u can see?

Comment: @neetuyadav : what is `maxqty` here?

Comment: i would suggest that put alert in all condition and check in which condition it goes and then verify the conditions and code.

Comment: (1) format properly your code (shift ctrl f or shift ctrl j on some editor should not be *that hard* to do) (2) be more specific about what's going on

Comment: @OlivierPons i have edited the question

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i have edited the question

Comment: @AlexOdenthal  i have edited the question

Comment: @Fred-ii-  dude i have put the image of error page

Comment: @OlivierPons   i have put the image of error page

Comment: Please post the code lines from the errors.